# New Drupal theme includes garland CSS file?

Tags: drupal, themes

I have been creating many Drupal themes already, but this one, somehow, includes the style.css file from garland when I visit the home page. Yes. Any other page does not include that core file (as I would expect.)

The home page (node/1) was made the default page (like on my other sites). The .info file and other theme pages are defined as in the other themes, so I'm not too sure what could make it go wrong.

If you have any idea, let me know. The site (still unfinished) is here: http://ic.m2osw.com/

Thank you.
Alexis

Answer (score 1):

It is allways worth clearing caches after you do things such as change theme. It could be that something was cached for that page.

Comment: I agree... and I had cleared the cache many times (in Performance). I'm thinking it may have been a module/theme thing that only update.php would clear for sure. Now I'm not sure that was it, but it works 8-)

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is go into the codebase and look for the definition of the "drupal_add_css", in includes/common.inc, line 1754, and temporarily add a couple of lines of code to print out the function parameters and a debug_backtrace() call to a log file. That way you can see where in your site the call to add Garland's style.css page is coming from.

Comment: Hmmm... I actually changed several things to fix another problem and the garland theme is gone! The main change was to add a template.php in there... Still, I don't understand the link with the problem.

Thank you for you answer, I'd probably do that next time. 8-)

Comment: I'm with [Jeremy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/56672/jeremy-french) caches can be stubborn. Increase your drupal love by using drush. Drush has a "Clear Cache" command that I wouldn't theme without (among other great features)